Is 125% DPI Scaling in reality actually 120% on Windows?
At Windows Settings -> System -> Display - Scale and layout, you'll be able to find a dropdown to change percentages for the DPI Scaling.
 
At Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop there's a LogPixels value.
If your Display DPI is set to 100% it doesn't say 100 though.
If your DPI is set to 125% it says 120. Note: It doesn't say 125.

 
Does this mean that 125% in reality is 120% ?

The answer is that 125% doesn't mean 120%. But it means 120 DPI. This is because 100% isn't 100 DPI, but 96 DPI instead, and the 125% as a factor bases it off that.
 
At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dpi-related-apis-and-registry-settings?view=windows-11#table-2-dpi-scale-factors
It turns out that 125% is the Scale Factor for the DPI, it is NOT the actual raw value for the DPI.
The Settings don't clarify the actual value.
This is a very important detail, as it matters if anyone wants to do manual math or anything.
 
125% is 125% as a percentage for the Scale Factor.
96 DPI is represented as 100%
And the 125% would point to 120 DPI. That's why LogPixels says 120.
 


96 corresponds to 100%, as shown in Table 2 DPI Scale Factors

